# How to add UIView over UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I want to add an `UIView` over my table view in my `tableViewController` class and under the NavigationBar. If I add it like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.manualView];
```

It is placed above the UITableView (actually I want to have them on the same z-index). I also want to remove the UIView programmatically when the user pushes a certain button.

Comment: No two view's can be at the exact same z-index because of the way ios handles the view hierarchy (the one on top would essentially be undefined). Do you want your view and the tableview stacked vertically? In that case you may be looking for a tableview header.

Comment: Yes I want to stack them vertically. If I add the UIView in the Storyboard it is possible to put the view over the UITableView however If I remove the UIView programmatically the space of the UIView remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two way to tackle this problem.
Naive (create your view and add it to subviews):

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

This introduces a whole host of issues related to layout placing and space conflicts.

Better Solution:
Return a header view or footer view for the appropriate section of your table via:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

This method is part of the UITableViewDelegate protocol which UITableViewController conforms to by default.

Answer (score 5):

`UITableViewController's` view is a `UITableView`, so adding a subview to it is probably not what you're looking for.  I think the best solution is to use a `UIViewController` instead.  It can behave just like a `UITableViewController` if you give it a tableView that covers the whole (`UIView`) view.

Then your code using `addSubview` (and `removeSubview` as suggested by @Literphor) will work just fine.

The stacking will take care of itself as long as you add the view after you add the table view.

Comment: This answer should have more upvotes. The most flexible thing to do, like @danh said is to use a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[self.view removeSubview:self.manualView];` in response to a user pressing a button. And  you can't have the two views with the same Z-index but you can change a view's depth by referring to the **Managing the View Hierarchy** section of Apple's [UIView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)